# RecyclerView is not showing data from Firebase on my app Screen

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I want to show firebase data on my app screen using recyclerview. My app is running without any error but data is not showing in the screen. 
Please help
Here is my code:
Please check and help me to show data from firebase to app screen using recyclerview

**VenuesActivity.java**

```
package com.cornicore.icccricketworldcup2019;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class VenuesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mBlogList;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_venues);


        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Venues");
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mBlogList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myrecyclerview);
        mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



    }

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Blog> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Blog>()
                    .setQuery(mDatabase, Blog.class)
                    .build();

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();



        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.venue_row, parent, false);

                return new BlogViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position, Blog model) {
                // Bind the image_details object to the BlogViewHolder
                // ...

                holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                holder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                holder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImage());

            }
        };




//        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog,BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>
//                (Blog.class,R.layout.venue_row,BlogViewHolder.class,mDatabase) {
//            @Override
//            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BlogViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Blog model) {
//
//                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
//                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
//                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImage());
//
//            }
//
//            @NonNull
//            @Override
//            public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
//                return null;
//            }
//        };

        mBlogList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View mView;
        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title){
            TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }
        public void setDesc(String desc){
            TextView post_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            post_desc.setText(desc);
        }
        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
            ImageView post_Image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_Image);
        }
    }

}
```

venuesactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".VenuesActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myrecyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Blog.java**

```
package com.cornicore.icccricketworldcup2019;

public class Blog {

    private String title;
    private String desc;
    private String image;

    public Blog(String title, String desc, String image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


    public Blog(){

    }

}
```

**venue_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    android:elevation="90dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="248dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#121111">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="POST TITLE"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="POST DESC"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>


    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**build.gradel**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cornicore.icccricketworldcup2019"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines after setting the apdapter:

```
mBlogList.setAdapter(adapter);
mFirebaseAdapter.startListening();
```

Comment: Can you please add explanation what this does?

Comment: sorry for late reply    mBlogList.setAdapter(adapter); // it will set the adapter 
and and   mFirebaseAdapter.startListening(); // it will start loading the data from the internet .

Answer (score 0):

The solve this, please follow the steps:

1. Remove: `mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);`
2. Move the declaration of your `adapter` inside the `onCreate()` method.
3. Make your `adapter` varaible global:

   ```
   private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> adapter;
   ```
4. Remove `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>` from the `onCreate()` method.
5. Add the following lines of code in the `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       adapter.startListening();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       if(adapter != null) {
           adapter.stopListening();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Not Working. I Posted the edited code in the comments section. Please check that once

Comment: You forgot to add `mBlogList.setAdapter(adapter);` Add this line after the declaration of the adapter. Does it work now?

Comment: adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(options) {...
      };                                                     

        mBlogList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

Comment: Ok, do you have an error? Edit the question with the changed code.

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write wrong code. You may try with this way.

```
    public class SavedRestaurantListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private DatabaseReference mRestaurantReference;
        private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter mFirebaseAdapter;

        @Bind(R.id.recyclerView) RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurants);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);

            mRestaurantReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_RESTAURANTS);
            setUpFirebaseAdapter();
        }

        private void setUpFirebaseAdapter() {
            mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Restaurant, FirebaseRestaurantViewHolder>
                    (Restaurant.class, R.layout.restaurant_list_item, FirebaseRestaurantViewHolder.class, 
                        mRestaurantReference) {

                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(FirebaseRestaurantViewHolder viewHolder, 
                    Restaurant model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.bindRestaurant(model);
                }
            };
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mFirebaseAdapter.cleanup();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mFirebaseAdapter.startListening();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if(mFirebaseAdapter != null) {
                mFirebaseAdapter.stopListening();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple..kindly change the layout_height of your recyclerview from match_parent to wrap_content

Thank me later

Comment: Please provide a code snippet as an example of what you are proposing to make it easier to figure out where you are suggesting to make this change.

Comment: In your recycler view XML file. Add. android: layout_height="match_parent"